# ¿Como consumir Web API desde C# pasando un Json como parámetro?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Tengo el siguiente código donde realizo el consumo desde `JavaScript`

```
<script>
    function Login() {
        var Request = {
            User: "usuario",
            Password: "1234",
            Secret_Id: "JGJHASDH7656775ASD776",
            App_Id: "XXTYVFDR65432GBVCMNCBGDRT"
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { JsonLoginRequest: JSON.stringify(Request) },
            url: "api/test/Login",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#Returncode").val(Response.Returncode);
                $("#Message").val(Response.Message);
                $("#Token").val(Response.Token);
            }
        });


    }
</script>
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿como podría hacer este mismo consumo pero desde `C#` a través de `HttpClient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de nada me gustaría preguntarte si estas seguro de querer hacer una petición de ese tipo porque **tiene varios errores de diseño/seguridad**

- Las peticiones de este tipo, en las que se pasan datos sensibles, deberían ser de tipo `POST` pasando los datos sensibles en el cuerpo del mensaje
- Lo de pasar un `JSON` en un parámetro de la `QueryString` no es nada elegante

Por si no tienes mas remedio, el código `C#` que haría esa petición sería el siguiente:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Establecer la url que proporciona acceso al servidor que publica la API 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://servername/");

    // Configurar encabezados para que la petición de realice en formato JSON
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Obtener el texto JSON con los datos del login
    string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        User = "usuario",
        Password = "1234",
        Secret_Id = "JGJHASDH7656775ASD776",
        App_Id = "XXTYVFDR65432GBVCMNCBGDRT"
    });

    // Realizar la petición GET
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/auth/login?JsonLoginRequest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request)).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Obtener el resultado como objeto dynamic 
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("ReturnCode: {0}", result.Returncode);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", result.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", result.Token);
    }
}
```

La serialización JSON se realiza con la librería [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

En vez de usar objetos anónimos y `dymamic` también podrías usar clases que representen los datos de solicitud y de respuesta

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Secret_Id { get; set; }
    public string App_Id { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResponse
{
    public int Returncode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: el ejemplo que mencionas lo he visto en varias paginas al parecer es la unica forma de hacerlo , si te das cuenta la idea no es contruir la uri si que le pueda pasar parametros algo asi como     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/test/Login" , Request );  donde request es una clase

Comment: Hola @JHONATANSTEVENGUERREROHURTA, creo que en tu pegunta faltaría algo de información porque la petición que has puesto es solo para obtener el `Token` de seguridad. Lo que te he puesto yo (la segunda parte) gestionaría de forma automática el `Token` de seguridad. Si amplias la información te intento contestar con un ejemplo más concreto. Saludos

Comment: @JHONATANSTEVENGUERREROHURTA olvídalo, que creo que ahora he entendido lo que quieres, cuando tenga un rato cambio mi respuesta

Comment: Hola @JHONATANSTEVENGUERREROHURTA, he reescrito mi respuesta, espero que te sirva. Saludos