# Agregar parámetro adicional en un button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Desde C# creo un número **indefinido** de tablas ASP y las completo. Posteriormente, creo un botón para cada tabla.

```
// Creamos una tabla.
Table tabla = new Table();

// Creamos una fila.
TableRow fila = new TableRow();
ficha.Rows.Add(fila);

// Creamos la primera columna.
TableCell columna1 = new TableCell();
fila.Cells.Add(columna1);

// Creamos la segunda columna.
TableCell columna2 = new TableCell();
fila.Cells.Add(columna2);

// Creamos un botón debajo de la tabla.
LinkButton buttonFile = new LinkButton();
buttonFile.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
```

Me gustaría que, cuando hago clic en alguno de esos botones, acceder a los datos de su tabla respectiva. Es decir, que si hago clic en el botón que hay debajo de, por ejemplo, la tabla número 3, poder acceder a los datos de la tabla número 3. El problema es que no me deja acceder a la tabla porque la creo desde C#, no desde la parte cliente, y además, no creo siempre el mismo número de tablas: a veces creo una, otras veces creo dos, otras tres, etc.

¿Cómo puede saber button_Click a qué tabla me refiero para poder acceder a los datos de la tabla?

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Esta instrucción da error porque no reconoce el ID "tabla".
    string variable = tabla.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
    ...
}
```

Todo el código de este mensaje se encuentra en el mismo fichero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes a traves del sender, le haces un cast de Button y luego sacas el nombre del boton, con el nombre de boton podrias hacer una consulta usando JSon para recuperar los datos desde el cliente.

Aqui te viene un ejemplo de como hacerlo.
[¿Como consumir Web API desde C# pasando un Json como parámetro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3783/como-consumir-web-api-desde-c-pasando-un-json-como-par%C3%A1metro)

```
Button boton = (Button)sender;
```

En boton tendras el boton sobre el que has hecho click, y como sabes su nombre sabes a quien ha clickeado, luego con ese boton.Name tu puede buscar en un array de asociacion, por ejemplo, sobre que tabla debes buscar.

Comment: Saludo, yo te recomendaria que seas mas especifico con la respuesta, es decir si puedes añadir tu codigo, ya que las respuestas con enlaces externos se pueden ver afectadas si este deja de funcionar.

Comment: @IvanBotero Seguramente tengas razon, pero espero que no caduque ese link ya que es del propio stackoverflow en español ;)

Comment: Hola, Urko. Lo de ponerle un nombre a cada botón es una idea interesante, pero no entiendo la respuesta del enlace que adjuntaste (soy algo novato en C#). Dentro del procedimiento `button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)´, ¿cómo puedo, haciendo cast del sender, obtener el nombre del botón?, ¿sería mucho pedir que pusieras la instrucción? Es muy importante para mí... :( Muchas gracias por adelantado y un saludo.

Comment: Hola, te lo pongo en la respuesta en un minuto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Urko. Con este truco no tengo que estar complicándome la vida. :)